# Purpose of main method in Java web application

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm debugging a Tomcat web application and came across a class that has a main method with some test code in it.

Is there a way to tell if this is called from the web application?  Or was this just a way of the previous developer testing in their IDE environment?

Comment: It's typically an antiquated approach to write tests, use of something like junit or testng being a more modern/conventional approach.  Tomcat has its own main method to start tomcat and will not, to my knowledge, invoke any other main methods (unless it's directly called from a servlet or some such).

Comment: Your IDE should be able to show you the callers for a given method so you can ensure it's not in use. And if the method *is* in use, you'll get an error when you try to build.

Answer (score 0):

The `static void main()` method should not be called from the application but the best thing to know it is checking it by searching if the class name is referenced somewhere (a textual search on the class name on all projets of the app is better because reflection may be used). If you don't find any references, it is a good sign. If you have references on it, you should understand why.
Else, next, you should check that the class in not included in our war.
It it is in the war, you should exclude it by moving it in the test folder of your project (`src/test/java` in Maven/Gradle for example).

Is a test with bad design (no unit test) or is a useful test code ?
It depends on.
Sometimes, you need to do some tests without unit test because you don't master the environment you try to test (a remote webservice, data that you don't master because external, etc...), so you don't want that the build of your application fails because of it. Generally, unit tests are played automatically in the build.
So, you should not use a unit test for this kind of test but rather a `static void main()`. In this way, you can play your manual test when you want and whatever the result is, you have no build failure.

If you notice that the test was done for this kind of need, you should add a Java comment about it. Otherwise, if the test is reproductible and relies on inner services of your application and also don't rely on changing database data, you should add a `FIXME` comment in order to indicate that it should be turned into a unit test.